# Hangouts and Chrome tabs are not separate sound mixers

Tags: google-chrome, audio, google-hangouts

How can I get hangouts and my youtube to be separate sound/volume mixers on windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the latest version of Google Chrome.

In the bottom right of the task bar, you will find the audio icon, right click on that icon and select 'Open Volume Mixer'

Youtube will be shown as 'Adobe Flash Player'

and Google Hangouts will be listed there as 'Hangouts'

You can change the volume of either with the shown volume selectors.

Comment: YouTube doesn't necessarily have to use Flash.

Comment: True, but I am sure for the purpose of this, it is commonly how the volume is managed, at least on the various machines I have used it is the most common form of volume control. Either way, the Windows volume mixer specifies chrome, hangouts or flash separately, so the answer would be based upon the users setup.